# Route not being executed in my NodeJS / Express / Typescript app

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I have a route '/api/users' that somehow is not being handled by my routes definition. I cannot spot what's wrong but every time I try to access /api/users from the browser, the browser stays in a constant loop.

app.ts

```
import * as express from "express"
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser"
import * as mongoose from "mongoose"
import {Config as config} from "./config"

let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
})) 

//routes:
import * as userRouter from './Routes/userRoutes'
app.use('/api/Users', userRouter.routes);

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('server is up');
})
```

userRoutes.ts

```
import * as express from "express"

export function routes() : express.Router {
    let userRouter = express.Router();

    userRouter.route('/')
        .get(function(req,res ) {
            res.send('blah')
        }) 

    return userRouter;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My TypeScript is rusty, but I believe you are passing your function `routes` to `app.use` instead of the router instance that it returns.

```
app.use('/api/Users', userRouter.routes);
```

Should become

```
app.use('/api/Users', userRouter.routes());
```